# 123-reg upgraded, now PHP include has stopped working

Tags: php, html

My website uses PHP include to bring-in all sorts of things as .html files and dumps them into my main page. It was working flawlessly - until my host, "upgraded" my package, and now it's stopped working completely. When they've tinkered about, they moved everything around and now the folder where everything was kept has been changed. It might be a path problem, but I've updated the .htaccess and it's still not working. I've tried a few tricks in my index file and that still doesn't work. Nightmare !

Can anyone help ?

Thanks !

```
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link href="_CustomCSS/CustomCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <?php include_path = ".:/home/MyUserName/public_html/" ?>
    <?php define("HTTP_ROOT1", "http://www.tunedinevents.co.uk"); ?>
    <link href="<?=HTTP_ROOT1?>/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Red_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?=HTTP_ROOT1?>/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Green_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?=HTTP_ROOT1?>/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Blue_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
   <?php include_path = ".:/home/MyUserName/public_html/" ?>
   <div class="<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Red_CSS.html'; ?>"></div>
   <div class="<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Green_CSS.html'; ?>"></div>
   <div class="<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Blue_CSS.html'; ?>"></div>
   <div class="Class_Box_1" id="ID_Text_Red">If PHP works properly, this text will be Red</div>
   <div class="Class_Box_2" id="ID_Text_Green">If PHP works properly, this text will be Green</div>
   <div class="Class_Box_3" id="ID_Text_Blue">If PHP works properly, this text will be Blue</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your current .htaccess?

Comment: #AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php index.cgi index.wml indexHomepage.html 
php_value include_path ".:/home/MyUserName/public_html/"

Comment: Oh, and the live Testing page is here :

http://tunedinevents.co.uk/__Testing/Include_PHP/

Comment: When I test that page and view console, I get this error :

%3C:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Hmmmmmmmm..... I thought 404 was something missing ???

This makes no sense at all

Comment: That `include_path` looks suspect to me. Are you sure that the leading `.:` should be there?

Comment: To be honest, I've been trawling the net and different forums for different things to try.... consistently advice does seem to be to use that.... though I've not come across it before

I've tried it other ways, but still doesn't work

Comment: My website is about to be reset... so currently it's out of action..... It might be an error their  end, I guess I'll see soon. I'll post a progress comment soon, see what's going on

Comment: Right, it's back online now, after a reset and still not working... I just can't see what I'm doing wrong :-(

http://tunedinevents.co.uk/__Testing/Include_PHP/

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaaand the answer is.... having finally got some decent tech support from someone who knows what they're talking about at 123-reg..... (and I wish they told me this right from the start)..... Drumroll Maestro, please.....

AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php70___lsphp .php .htm .html

That - plonked in .htaccess

I'm actually using it as part of a block to make extra sure :

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php index.cgi index.wml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php70___lsphp .php .htm .html

I would never in a million years known about this simple line of code. I can just about code basic html, css and JS.... PHP and Handlers is a whole new ballgame.

I really hope this can help anyone reading this looking for the same solution. The "70" denotes the version of PHP you have specified on your Hosting package. For that, log into your Hosting CPanel. 70 is PHP 7.0, 71, is PHP 7.1 etc

Working html Code in the end :

```
<html>


<head>

          <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

      
      <link href="_CustomCSS/CustomCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      
      
     <?php define("HTTP_ROOT", "http://www.tunedinevents.co.uk");?>  
     
     
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Red_CSS.html'; ?>
  
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Green_CSS.html'; ?>
  
  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/__Testing/Include_PHP/_CustomCSS/Include_Blue_CSS.html'; ?>


 </head>



<body>
   

  <div class="Class_Box_1" id="ID_Text_Red">If PHP works properly, this text will be Red</div>
  
  <div class="Class_Box_2" id="ID_Text_Green">If PHP works properly, this text will be Green</div>
  
  <div class="Class_Box_3" id="ID_Text_Blue">If PHP works properly, this text will be Blue</div>

  
</body>

      

</html>
```

Comment: Result :

http://www.tunedinevents.co.uk/__Testing/Include_PHP/